# Structural equation modeling identification question

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

Could someone please assist me in identifying whether my model is underidentified, just identified, or overidentified based on the post-estimation results of my Structural Equation Modeling? I have 16 observed variables and 2 latent variables, with a sample size of 921.

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble**

The topic of identification has been covered countless times on CV (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321860/identification-sem-model), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605244/sem-difference-between-unidentified-underidentified-and-underdetermined-model)), so I will keep my response short.

**Answer**

As you may know, a [structural equation model (SEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) is overidentified when the number of sample moments is greater than the number the number of estimated parameters. You have $\frac{16(16+1)}{2}$ = 136 distinct sample moments and not even half that many parameters to estimate, so your model would certainly be **overidentified**.

For more information on SEM model identification see [David Kenny's post on the topic](https://davidakenny.net/cm/identify_formal.htm) and [Bollen (1989)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471011711).

**References**

Bollen, K. A. (1989). Structural equations with latent variables (Vol. 210). John Wiley & Sons.